# Connection refused when trying to connect with MQTT+Tasmota

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I've done my googling on this and I have really tried to fix this before posting my question here.

**System:** Raspberry Pi B+ (Latest Raspbian), Wifi

**Problem:** 
When I try to run this:
*mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.121 -t cmnd/DVES_1A6953_fb/cmnd/Power1 -m off*
I get "Error: Connection refused"

**What I know:**
Mosquitto is installed on 192.168.1.100 (RPi)
Sonoff Basic Pow is located at 192.168.1.121
I've tried with mosquitto -d.
And sudo systemctl enable mosquitto.service.

mosquitto -v gives me:
1579784576: mosquitto version 1.5.7 starting
1579784576: Using default config.
1579784576: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1579784576: Error: Address already in use

[image: Snoff Basic Pow with Tasmota configuration]

[image: Sonof Basic Pow console shows this:]

I really don't know what else to do now :)

Hope you can help me!

/ Oskar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to publish directly to device (192.168.1.121) not to the broker (192.168.1.100)

You need to send messages to the broker, which will forward them to the device (Assuming it's subscribed to the right topic)

```
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.100 -t cmnd/DVES_1A6953_fb/cmnd/Power1 -m off
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I need to add that this is my first day with MQTT! Wow, thank you very much! 

Okey, so I have the broker on the RPi, which is subscribed to the topic that is defined by (and on) the device... And when that subscription (and broker) is running, I send (and receive) all data through the broker to the device?

Comment: No, the device is subscribed to a specific topic, the mosquitto_pub client publishes a message on that topic to the broker, which delivers it to the subscribed device (there may be 0 to n subscribed devices). Yes to all data goes via the broker.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Really helps!